# How to add @lang to my label form on laravel

Tags: php, html, css, laravel

I'm trying to add an @lang or traduction into my label form with laravel but it doesn't recognize it some one could help me with that structure?

I've tried this not far yet

```
{!! Form::label('full_name', ('@lang(modules.employees.createTitle)'), [$options]) !!}


{!! Form::label('name','@lang'('modules.employees.fullName')'') !!}

{!! Form::label('full_name','@lang('modules.employees.fullName')') !!}
```

also i have the variable on lang create it in an modules php file with an array

```
<form action="create" method="POST">
    {{ csrf_field() }}

    <div class="form-group">

        {!! Form::label('full_name','@lang('modules.employees.fullName')') !!}
        {!! Form::text('full_name', null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'required' => 'required', 'autocomplete' => 'off']) !!}
    </div>
</form>
```

Those are the errors I have been getting:

> syntax error, unexpected 'translator' (T_STRING), expecting ')' 
>   syntax error, unexpected 'translator' (T_STRING)

Comment: Remove the outer quotes from `'@lang('modules.employees.fullName')'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of issues, to start you are putting it through in quotation marks, that will parse it as a string. You are also trying to use a blade helper in an incorrect manner.

An example of what you should be doing:

```
{{ Form::label('full_name', __('modules.employees.fullName')) }}
```

The double underscore `__('lang')` is the Laravel (non blade) equivalent to `@lang('lang')`.

See more [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/localization).

Comment: Thank you so much, i'm new with laravel and blade